# Relationship between Parameter set context and model mode?

Tags: origen-sdk

Origen has [modes](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/models/modes/) for the top level DUT and IP.  However, the mode [API](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/api/Origen/ChipMode.html) doesn't allow the flexibility to define attributes at will.  There are pre-defined attributes, some of which (e.g. typ_voltage) look specific to a particular company or device.

In contrast, the [Parameters module](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/models/parameters/) does allow flexible parameter/attribute definitions to be created within a 'context'.  What is really the conceptual difference between a chip 'mode' and a parameter 'context'?  They both require the user to set them.

```
add_mode :mymode do |m|
  m.typ_voltage = 1.0.V
  # I believe I am limited to what I can define here
end

define_params :mycontext do |params|
  params.i.can.put.whatever.i.want = 'bdedkje'
end
```

They both contain methods [with_modes](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/api/Origen/Model.html#with_mode-instance_method) and [with_params](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/api/Origen/Parameters.html#with_params-instance_method) that look similar in function.  Why not make the mode attributes work exactly like the more flexible params API?

thx

Comment: Don't really understand what you are asking, can you elaborate?

Comment: Updated the original question as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being able to arbitrarily add named attributes to a mode seems like a good idea to me, but you are right that it is not supported today.

No particular reason for that other than nobody has seen a need for it until now, but there would be no problems accepting a PR to add it.

Ideally, when implementing that, it would be good to try and do it via a module which can then be included into other classes to provide the same functionality e.g. to give pins, bits, etc. the same ability.

Comment: thanks Ginty.  Do you think it would be OK to actually use the Parameter:Sets to store the attributes whatever model uses this new module?  I.e. Delegate the attribute handling to the Paramter::Set by using the same ID for both the object mode and the parameter context.

Comment: Don't think I would use the parameter APIs directly for this, they should be different things. You are really looking for a kind of AdHocAttributes feature to be added to the mode object, so I would favor creating such a module and then mixing that in to other objects in the eco-system where we want similar functionality.

Comment: Could you sketch out the api as you see it? That would help me get started.  thx